# Not able to create a select tag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.4

I have a models.py file:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (('FRESHMAN', 'HOD'),('SOPHOMORE', 'Staff_Member'),)
    #phone = models.CharField(max_length = 10, null = True)
    Designation = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null = False,choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,default='FRESHMAN')
```

When I run the **python manage.py migrate** command,it's displays an error: **django.db.utils.InternalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'Designation'")**

I have seen the documentation:[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Can anyone please point what I am doing wrong in this implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the typical accepted structure:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    FRESHMAN = 'HOD'
    SOPHOMORE = 'Staff_Member'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
    )
    Designation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES, default='HOD')
```

The reason (or one of the reasons) you are running into problems is because the first item in each choices tuple designates what will be stored in the database, while the second designates what will be shown on a dropdown on a form. So your default needs to be what will be stored in the database by default. I'm assuming it's 'HOD' you want stored in the database by default, so I've set up my example that way.

Comment: I had tried this also,it was some migration problem as even when I commented these lines,error appeared,thanks for the answer.

Comment: what happens if you delete your latest migration file and makemigrations again after implementing the changes in my answer? I think choices might be stored in migrations files but I'm not sure.

Comment: It displayed:Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: Just to be clear you:

1) deleted the latest migration file in your migrations folder for the project
2) ran `python manage.py makemigrations appname`
3) ran `python manage.py migrate`